# hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method

Tags: shell, hwclock

---

I'm using the **Ubuntu bash shell provided by Windows 10** and I want to see my hardware clock time by using hwclock but I keep getting Errors.

### hwclock

```sh
root@DESKTOP:/home/blondinl# hwclock
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
hwclock: Use the --debug option to see the details of our search for an access method.
```

### When I use the --debug option

```sh
root@DESKTOP:/home/blondinl# hwclock -- debug
hwclock from util-linux 2.27.1
hwclock: cannot open /dev/rtc: No such file or directory
No usable clock interface found.
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
```

### I have tried to use timedatectl

```sh
root@DESKTOP:/home/blondinl# timedatectl
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
```

I have searched an answer on the internet but couldn't found any.
Maybe it's because I'm using the linux bash on Windows I don't know.
**I look forward to your help**

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a wsl bug that may yet to be fixed. I am still facing it today.

[https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5324](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4245)

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4245

Sorry I don't really have time to provide extra info or read into it but maybe you could.